# RIP, David Prowse

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

David Prowse, actor of Darth Vader in the first Star Wars film, has [died](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-55117704) today at the age of 85 after a short illness. He was long known as the actor of Darth Vader, but had a different voice actor used over his voice, due to [his accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQFho0_G1VI) (a distinctive west country accent that did not make him sound very menacing as *a dark Lord of the Sith*). It has been reported that he was close to rival bodybuilder competitors Arnold Schwarzenegger and Lou Ferrigno (from TV's *Incredible Hulk*) He also featured in a number of other films, including:

- The Horror of Frankenstein
- Dr Who (1 episode - "The Time Monster")
- Frankenstein and the Monster from Hell
- Space: 1999
- The People that Time forgot
- Star Wars: The Empire Strikes back
- Star Wars: Return of the Jedi

He was also known as the Green Code man, a character in British road safety aimed at children, which earned him an MBE. *May the force always be with him.*

Comment: Someone else got there first ... maybe you could post this as an answer on the other RIP post?

Comment: @Randal'Thor on it, I didn't see the first one